# Compiler error with template member function

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

My compiler gives me this error, and i do not understand why.

```
`P3_A2.o: In function `allocateAlot(_sync*)':
/home/***/workspace_qnx/P3_A2/P3_A2.cpp:69: undefined reference to `int* 
StaticMem::allocate<int>(int*)'`
```

Here is `P3_A2.cpp`:

> `void allocateAlot(sem_t * sleepHere)`
>   {
>
> > `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)`
> >     `{`
> >
> > > `Int32 * t = StaticMem::allocate(t);`
> >
> > `}`
> >     `sem_wait(sleepHere);`
>
> }

Here's `StaticMem.h`:

> class StaticMem
>   `{`
>   `...`
>
> > `template <class T> static T * allocate(T * ptr);`
>
> `}`

Here's `StaticMem.cpp`:

> `template <class T>`
>   `T * StaticMem::allocate(T * ptr)`
>   `{`
>
> > `ptr = (T*) reserveContiguousMemory(sizeof(T));`
> >      `return ptr;`
>
> `}`

Can someone explain where this error comes from?

Comment: Template functions have to be defined in *header* files. The definition has to be visible everywhere it is used. Don't attempt to define template functions in a `.cpp` file (unless this is the only file you use these functions in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, template functions are different from normal functions. In particular, you can't put them in to a C++ source file, compile them separately, and then expect the code to link. The reason for this is that C++ templates aren't code - they're *templates* for code - and are only instantiated and compiled when they're needed.

Because you've put the implementation of your template function `allocate` into a .cpp file, the program won't link. To fix this, move the implementation of this function into the `StaticMem.h` file. That way, any file that includes `StaticMem.h` will see the implementation of the template, so when the template is instantiated the implementation will be generated and compiled, fixing your linker error.

Hope this helps!